How can I set Chrome (and Brave) to _always_ pretty-print JSON results without installing an extension?
As a software engineer, I often visits JSON endpoints.
They look like this: https://dummyjson.com/test
I don't want to manually click the "Pretty-print" checkbox every time.


How can I change a browser setting to make the "Pretty-print" checkbox checked by default?
I don't want to install extensions. (I like keeping my browsers extension-free.)

Bonus questions:

Why would anyone not want Pretty-print enabled?
And why wouldn't it at least be enabled by default?


Use Edge if you can - it pretty prints only (no choice not to)

added a bounty because i totally agree with this: "why would anyone not want Pretty-print enabled? And why wouldn't it at least be enabled by default?"

Also, I'm on latest Chrome, and I think I'm missing something: https://i.imgur.com/mHExrk4.png | Example JSON: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LearnWebCode/json-example/master/animals-2.json | I'm not not using the F12 module at all, of course.

Also - @rockstardev ooohhh I get what I missed earlier! Your'e viewing "https://dummyjson.com/test/index.html". That's an HTML file. There's no indication to the browser that it's JSON. Why are you viewing it like that? I get that the site is "dummyJSON" but you usually don't view JSON as HTML, aren't you? It's almost like that "pretty print" option is built-into the site?

Also ( haha, just found it online ) - is Firefox an option? It seems to do that natively

@Netan Thanks but I'm on the latest Brave and latest Chrome in Ubuntu, and even when I visit JSON documents that say content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 in the response header, they appear with the Pretty-print box unchecked.


Navigate to an API or JSON resource using the provided URL.
Open the developer tools by pressing F12.
Go to the "Source" tab.
Open a source file or press CTRL-P.
Choose the JSON file.
Select "Pretty Print" at the top.
Voila! You now have a nicely formatted, human-readable JSON.


OP isn't asking how to pretty print a JSON, they are asking how to ALWAYS pretty print EVERY JSON.
